# Maximum of items a "dump()" on an array will show?

Tags: php, arrays, object, dump

When I dump() a large array after a certain amount of items in the array it will only display something like this: 108 => {#249 …6}. Where ...6 is the number of items in the (sub)array.

As in the code provided you can see that the switching point of this particular array is at key 107. All keys before show all the data and all keys after only show something similar to "{#249 …6}".

Is there a way so display all values of a large array?

```
106 => {#251 ▼
  +"average": 11097598.72
  +"date": "2018-06-16"
  +"highest": 13999997.93
  +"lowest": 6743999.48
  +"order_count": 5
  +"volume": 5
}
107 => {#250 ▼
  +"average": 15222222.0
   …5
}
108 => {#249 …6}
109 => {#248 …6}
110 => {#247 …6}
```

Comment: Dump it in a loop maybe?

Comment: use echo'<pre>';print_r($yourArray);die;

Comment: use `CTRL + F` if you need to find anything within array.

Comment: `dump()` is not a php function, are you using `var_dump()` or is this function provided by a framework?